# Flattening a parent/child object-chain, merging values along the way

Tags: c#, algorithm, parent-child, flatten

We have been staring at this problem for ages, losing valuable time.

We have these objects, lets call them *Components*. Our application allows you to create a *new Component*, based on an *existing Component*.

All values of the parent are 'inherited' (read: accessible via a `component.Parent` property) **unless** you override a value -- e.g. you want to give it a new name, but keep the rest of the parent values.

```
// Exiting parent-child object chain
BaseObject      {Id = 1, Name = "Base", Description = "Base description", Notes = "Awesome object", ParentId = null}
ChildObject1    {Id = 2, Name = "", Description = "", Notes = "", ParentId = 1}
ChildObject2    {Id = 3, Name = "Custom Name", Description = "", Notes = "", ParentId = 2}
ChildObject3    {Id = 4, Name = "", Description = "Final object", Notes = "", ParentId = 3}
```

Now I want to flatten this from the TOP DOWN, using existing values of the parent for any empty values on the child.

```
// End result after flattening/merging
ChildObject3    {Id = 4, Name = "Custom Name", Description = "Final object", Notes = "Awesome object", ParentId = 3}
```

**Noteworthy:** there is no child property, only the child knows about a parent. The parent is unaware of the child.

How to solve this without ugly `while(child.Parent != null)` constructions and creating `previousComponent`, `currentComponent`, etc. objects to keep track of set values.

Comment: This looks like a simple problem to solve, question is, how are you storing these properties? Since you say your "application" lets you create new components based on existing, I'm assuming you are not talking about c# inheritance but rather some proprietary storage mechanism? Do you have some sort of key/value dictionary on the component? Are all properties on the children the same as the properties on the parents or can children add new properties? (also have you tried implementing this in a simple loop - if so why was it "too ugly" and why did you get stuck?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a recursive `DeepCopy` method, something like:

```
public class ComponentClass()
{
   public ComponentClass DeepCopy(ComponentClass comp)
   {
       CopyAllNonEmptyPropertiesTo(comp);
       if (comp.StillHasEmptyProperties())
          return Parent.DeepCopy(comp);
       else
          return comp;
   }
}
```

Comment: @FredFickleberryIII Great! Was my code above useful and/or did it answer your question? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dictionary of your data objects so you lookup your parents.

For each of the items you have, do a recursive lookup of parent values when:

- You don't have a value for one of the target properties
- You have a parent

E.g. (the Dump() command is from LinqPad)

```
var data = new List<Bob>
{
    new Bob { Id = 1, Name = "Base", Description = "Base description", Notes = "Awesome object", ParentId = null },
    new Bob { Id = 2, Name = "", Description = "", Notes = "", ParentId = 1 },
    new Bob { Id = 3, Name = "Custom Name", Description = "", Notes = "", ParentId = 2 },
    new Bob { Id = 4, Name = "", Description = "Final object", Notes = "", ParentId = 3 },
};
var map = data.ToDictionary(d => d.Id, d => d);

data.ForEach(row => CopyFromParent(map, row, row.ParentId.HasValue ? map[row.ParentId.Value] : null));
data.Dump();

}

void CopyFromParent(Dictionary<int, Bob> map, Bob target, Bob current)
{
    // set properties
    if (current != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(target.Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(current.Name)) target.Name = current.Name;
    if (current != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(target.Description) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(current.Description)) target.Description = current.Description;
    if (current != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(target.Notes) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(current.Notes)) target.Notes = current.Notes;

    // dive deeper if we need to, and if we can
    var needToDive = string.IsNullOrEmpty(target.Name) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(target.Description) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(target.Notes);
    var canDive = current != null && current.ParentId.HasValue && map.ContainsKey(current.ParentId.Value);
    if (needToDive && canDive)
    {
        CopyFromParent(map, target, map[current.ParentId.Value]);
    }
}

class Bob
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```